# React Hook Form Controller and React-Bootstrap Form.Check radio

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form and React-Bootstrap and I'm trying to set up a radio button group.

`Radio 1` should be selected by default and then the user can switch between them.

Because I'm using `Form.Check` from React-Bootstrap I'm wrapping it in a React Hook Form `Controller` ([Wrapper component for controlled inputs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)).

It should look like this:

[image: radio buttons]

This works fine for all the normal text inputs:

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="name"
  defaultValue=""
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref } }) => (
    <Form.Control
      type="text"
      onChange={onChange}
      placeholder="Name"
      value={value}
      isInvalid={!!errors.name}
      ref={ref}
    />
  )}
/>
```

But for radio boxes this doesn't seem to work. It's rendered without a default checked box, I can select both of them, and the submitted data is always the same.

Here's the code for the radio boxes:

```js
Controller
  control={control}
  name="myradiovalue"
  defaultValue="radio1"
  render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
    <>
      <Form.Check
        onChange={onChange}
        type="radio"
        label="Radio 1"
        id="formAdapterRadio1"
        value="radio1"
      />
      <Form.Check
        onChange={onChange}
        type="radio"
        label="Radio 2"
        id="formAdapterRadio2"
        value="radio2"
      />
    </>
  )}
/>
```

How should this look? Separate `Controller`s maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-forms-in-react-using-react-hook-form/#how-to-use-other-input-types-with-react-hook-form

It seems with react-bootstrap it is not necessary to go to the Controller/useController path suggested by the react-hook-form documentation.

For each <Form.Check> element, just use ...register("foo") for each of the checkboxes making up the "foo" selection.

```
    <Form.Check
      value="bar"
      type="radio"
      label="This is a bar"
      {...register("foo")}
    />
    <Form.Check
      value="woozle"
      type="radio"
      label="This is a woozle"
      {...register("foo")}
    />
```